# Kivy - Labels, Buttons and Layouts

Tags: python, button, layout, kivy, label

HelloWorld!
First of all, I'm new to the English version of this page. I think my English is good, but if make any mistakes let me know and I'll fix it. Second, the code I wrote (I'll show you in a minute) is probably not the most efficient, but I only want it to work. Here's the thing...

I'm practicing with kivy and I decided to make a program which will create an anagram out of a list of words, the user will have to guess the word and the program will tell if it is correct or not. I made a program that does that, but I was having problems with the 'new word' button (a new game, so to speak), so I've decided to make a new code (I'll show you the old version in a comment). And this new code fails from the beginning. When I add the labels and buttons, not only I can't click on them, but they are also shown on the bottom-left part of the screen, and very small. The image shows the result: [Labels, Buttons and RelativeLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KLWw.jpg).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from random import choice, shuffle
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (.10, .54, 1, 1)
Window.size = (500,300)

# ------- THIS PART SHOULD GO ON A SEPARATE FILE ----------------------------
list_of_words = ['ELEPHANT', 'LION', 'COCODRILE', 'MONKEY', 'KANGAROO']

def create_anagram():
    # Takes a word from the list and shuffles the letters to create the anagram
    choices = choice(list_of_words)
    list_letters = []
    for item in choices:
        list_letters.append(item)
    shuffle(list_letters)
    choices = ''.join(list_letters)

    return choices
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Anagram(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Anagram, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # These are all variables which will be used later on.

        self.choices = create_anagram()
        self.window = RelativeLayout()
        self.font_size = 20                     
        self.letters, self.underscores = [],[]  
        self.ind = 0                            # Index used on chose_letter()
        self.size_x, self.size_y = 100, 50      # Sizes for the labels and button
        self.pos_x = 0                          # Initial position for the labels and buttons
        self.word = ''                          # will concatonate the letters choosen

        self.new_game()

    def new_game(self):
        with self.canvas.after:
            for item in self.choices:
                self.letters.append(Button(text=item,
                                        size_hint=(1/len(self.choices), 0.2),
                                        pos_hint = {'x': self.pos_x, 'top': .8},
                                        font_size = self.font_size,
                                        color='#688FF8',
                                        background_color = '#1F48F2',
                                        disabled = False))

                self.underscores.append(Label(text='_',
                                        size_hint=(1/len(self.choices), 0.2),
                                        pos_hint = {'x': self.pos_x, 'top': 0.4},
                                        size=(self.size_x, self.size_y),
                                        font_size = self.font_size,
                                        color = '#FFFFFF'))

                self.pos_x += 1/len(self.choices)

            # Adding buttons for the letters and the underscores.
        for item in self.letters:
            self.window.add_widget(item)
        for item in self.underscores:
            self.window.add_widget(item)

class MainAnagramApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Anagram()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainAnagramApp().run()'''
```

So that's it. That's the code and the problem. Any idea why this happens?

By the way, I've tried without the "with self.canvas" but it doesn't even show the widgets. I also tried changing the layout (Grid, Anchor, etc.), but the problem is exactly the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `self.window = RelativeLayout()` or the `with self.canvas.after:`. Here is a modified version of your `Anagram` class:

```
class Anagram(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Anagram, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # These are all variables which will be used later on.

        self.choices = create_anagram()
        # self.window = RelativeLayout()
        self.font_size = 20
        self.letters, self.underscores = [],[]
        self.ind = 0                            # Index used on chose_letter()
        self.size_x, self.size_y = 100, 50      # Sizes for the labels and button
        self.pos_x = 0                          # Initial position for the labels and buttons
        self.word = ''                          # will concatonate the letters choosen

        self.new_game()

    def new_game(self):
        # with self.canvas.after:
        for item in self.choices:
            self.letters.append(Button(text=item,
                                    size_hint=(1/len(self.choices), 0.2),
                                    pos_hint = {'x': self.pos_x, 'top': .8},
                                    font_size = self.font_size,
                                    color='#688FF8',
                                    background_color = '#1F48F2',
                                    disabled = False))

            self.underscores.append(Label(text='_',
                                    size_hint=(1/len(self.choices), 0.2),
                                    pos_hint = {'x': self.pos_x, 'top': 0.4},
                                    size=(self.size_x, self.size_y),
                                    font_size = self.font_size,
                                    color = '#FFFFFF'))

            self.pos_x += 1/len(self.choices)

        # Adding buttons for the letters and the underscores.
        for item in self.letters:
            self.add_widget(item)
        for item in self.underscores:
            self.add_widget(item)
```

And note that the `Buttons` and `Labels` are added using `self.add_widget()` not `self.window.add_widget()`.

In your code, when you create a `Button` inside a `with self.canvas.after:`, the canvas instructions for drawing a `Button` are added to the `canvas.after` of the `Anagram` instance. But the actual `Button` widget is not added. So you have an image of a `Button`, but it will not function as a `Button`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it works. In the first code I've tried (I forgot to show you in another comment) I used self.window = RelativeLayout() and the wigdets were shown on the window. Any idea why it didn't work this time? I'll show the code in the next answer.

Comment: Regarding the canvas.after, I actually didn't type that at first (only canvas). I thought about trying canvas.after to see if it worked and then I forgot to remove it. Thanks for that too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old version of the code. It's an answer to John Anderson.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from random import choice, shuffle
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (24/243, 132/243, 1, 1)
Window.size = (500,300)

list_of_words = ['ELEPHANT', 'LION', 'COCODRILE', 'MONKEY', 'KANGAROO']

def create_anagram():
    # Chooses a word from the list and shuffles the letters to create the anagram

    choices = choice(list_of_words)
    list_letters = []
    for item in choices:
        list_letters.append(item)
    shuffle(list_letters)
    choices = ''.join(list_letters)

    return choices

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):

        # These are all variables which will be used later on.
        
        self.choices = create_anagram()
        self.window = RelativeLayout()
        self.font_size = 20
        self.letters, self.underscores = [],[]
        self.ind = 0                         # Index used on chose_letter()
        self.size_x, self.size_y = 100, 50
        self.pos_x = 0
        self.word = ''                       # will concatonate the letters choosen.

        # Adding the buttons to the respectives lists.
        for letter in self.choices:
            self.window.add_widget(Button(text=letter,
                                        size_hint=(1/len(self.choices), 0.2),
                                        pos_hint = {'x': self.pos_x, 'top': .8},
                                        font_size = self.font_size,
                                        color='#688FF8',
                                        background_color = '#1F48F2',
                                        on_press = self.chose_letter,
                                        disabled = False))
            
            self.underscores.append(Label(text='_',
                                        size_hint=(1/len(self.choices), 0.2),
                                        pos_hint = {'x': self.pos_x, 'top': 0.4},
                                        size=(self.size_x, self.size_y),
                                        font_size = self.font_size,
                                        color = '#FFFFFF'))

            self.pos_x += 1/len(self.choices)

        # Adding buttons for the letters and the underscores.
        for item in self.letters:
            self.window.add_widget(item)
        for item in self.underscores:
            self.window.add_widget(item)            

        self.RESTART = Button(text='RESTART',
                                            size_hint=(0.2,0.1),
                                            font_size = 12,
                                            pos_hint = {'center_x': .5,'center_y': 0.1},
                                            background_color = '#B50E0E',
                                            on_press = self.on_press_restart)
        self.window.add_widget(self.RESTART)

        self.SORRY = Label(text='SORRY, WORNG WORD!',
                                            size_hint=(.8, .4),
                                            pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.45},
                                            font_size = self.font_size,
                                            color = '#1884F3')
        self.window.add_widget(self.SORRY)

        return self.window


    
    def chose_letter(self, instance):
        # When the user clicks on a letter, it adds that letter to the first empty label and to self.word
        
        if self.ind == len(self.choices):               # If we click a button when the word is complete (either correct or incorrect)
            return True                                 # This will allow the program not to add 1 to self.ind (and will not cursh)

        _choice = instance.text                         # Gets the text from the button
        # instance.disabled = True
        self.underscores[self.ind].text = _choice       # Changes the first underscore for the text in _choice
        self.ind += 1                                   # Adds 1 to the index counter
        self.word += _choice                            # Copies the word created, in order to compare it to the words on the list (in the next line)
        

        # It shows a message, either the word is correct or not.
        
        if len(self.choices) == len(self.word):
            if self.word in list_of_words:
                self.CONGRAT = Label(text='CONGRATULATIONS! THE WORD IS: ',
                                            size_hint=(.8, .4),
                                            pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.45},
                                            font_size = self.font_size)
                self.window.add_widget(self.CONGRAT)

                self.NEW = Button(text='NEW WORD',
                                            size_hint=(0.2,0.1),
                                            font_size = 12,
                                            pos_hint = {'center_x': .5,'center_y': 0.1},
                                            background_color = '#B50E0E',
                                            on_press = self.on_press_new)
                self.window.add_widget(self.NEW)
            else:
                self.SORRY.color = '#000000'

            
        


    def on_press_restart(self, instance):
        
        for item in range(len(self.underscores)):
            self.underscores[item].text = '_'


        self.ind = 0
        self.word = ''
        self.SORRY.color = '#1884F3'
        
    def on_press_new(self, instance):
        # self.choices = create_anagram()
        print(self.choices)
        
        self.window.remove_widget(instance)     # It owrks, but the game doesn't restart.
        self.window.remove_widget(self.CONGRAT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: By the way, I don't think it's because of the missing canvas. I've tried the second code without it and it still didn't work. But I can be wrong of course.

Comment: In this code, you are building the Buttons and Labels in the `build()`  method and returning `self.window` as the root widget of the `App`. In the code in your original post, the `self.window` was never actually used.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thank you again. I got it! And now that I see the code more carefully, I can see I can already make it better (I've already tried it). Thanks!